# I am trying to write a script to update the column values if they are null with incremental values if the column id is the same

Tags: sql-update, sql-insert

I am trying to write a SQL script to set the column values with incremental values based on the values of the id of the previous column. If the Job Id column is the same I would like the Employee column to be populated with incremental values.

[image]

I have this so far, but I'm not sure how to group it by JobID and reset the counter if they JobID changes:

DECLARE @employee INT
  SET @employee = 0

UPDATE dbo.JobEmployees
  SET Employees= @employees, @employees = @employees + 1 where Employees is null

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHp4k.png

Comment: Right now I currently have the values in the Employee column as null